# Shift Date not updated as Sit date

Tags: django, date

I designed two models: one model for storing Sitting date and another mode for storing Shifting date. Two model are linked by foreign key. Here is my two models:

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

Shift Model:

```
 class Shiftdate(models.Model):
    shift_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    sit_date = models.ForeignKey(Sitting,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Using Shift model I change existing sitting dates to other dates as:

```
Sitting Date     Shifting Date
2016-09-01       Sept. 15, 2016
2016-09-08       Sept. 19, 2016
```

Now I want to make shift date to a new sitting dates. For this I define following method in Sitting model:

```
def get_shift_date(self):
            return self.sit_date.shift_date
```

And this shift_date to be saved in the Sitting model. I define following save method:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):     

            self.sit_date = self.get_shift_date()
        super(Sitting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But this does not return shift dates as sitting dates. Could someone help me to fix this codes?

Answer (score 0):

You have contradictory if statements here. Your save method only calls `get_shift_date` if `sit_date` is blank; but inside that method, you only return something is `sit_date` is *not* blank. So sit_date can only ever be set to None.

Comment: So I changed get_shift_date() as:

Comment: So I changed get_shift_date() as:    
def get_shift_date(self):
        return self.sit_date.shift_date

and  save method
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        
            self.sit_date = self.get_shift_date()
        super(Sitting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
But still doesn't work

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer so that I can get workable solutions