# How to call one field from another model?

Tags: django

I want to call a field from another model. I am doing by

def get_shift_date(self):

```
for d in Shiftdate.objects.select_related('sit_date'):
   d.shift_date=self.sit_date
   return d.shift_date
```

from

```
class Shiftdate(models.Model):
    shift_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    sit_date = models.ForeignKey(Sitting,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

But it didn't work. Could some one help me to correctly call shift date in the get_shift_date method?

Edit:
Save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
           self.sit_date = self.get_shift_date(‌​) 
           super(Sitting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is this different from the question that you just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966759/shift-date-not-updated-as-sit-date

Comment: Yes, I couldn't figure out the working solutions

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `self.`, d is the object that is currently being iterated over.

```
for d in Shiftdate.objects.select_related('sit_date'):
    d.shift_date=self.sit_date
```

Note:

1. You won't actually be storing the value in the models since you don't `save()` it
2. Your return won't work since its outside the loop and even then it will only return the first.

Comment: Here is my save method:
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.sit_date = self.get_shift_date()
        super(Sitting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
How could I return all values?